# C# Progress<string> callback not invoked after IProgress.Report is called

Tags: c#, asynchronous

When I call IProgress.Report, the callback passed into the constructor of the Progress object is not being invoked.  In my specific case my callback is simply calling Console.WriteLine

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var driver = SeleniumUtility.CreateFirefoxDriver(@"C:\Users\david\source\repos\HelperLib\HelperLib\bin\Debug\drivers");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cool-proxy.net/proxies/http_proxy_list/sort:score/direction:desc");
    var progress = new Progress<string>(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
    await Scraper.ScrapeAsync(driver, RegexUtility.IPv4AndPortWithSeperatorRegexString, By.CssSelector("#main > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(23) > th > span.next > a"), progress);
}

public class Scraper
{
    public static async Task ScrapeAsync(IWebDriver driver, string regex, By nextPageButtonSelector, IProgress<string> progress, int nextPageButtonWaitTimeout = 20)
    {
        var matches = new List<Match>();
        do
        {
            var mc = Regex.Matches(driver.PageSource, regex);
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                matches.Add(m);
            }
            progress.Report($"Found {mc.Count} matches on {driver.Url}");
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(nextPageButtonWaitTimeout));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(nextPageButtonSelector));
            var nextPageButton = driver.FindElement(nextPageButtonSelector);
            nextPageButton.Click();
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [mcve] that doesn't involve Selenium? It would be a lot easier to help at that point.

Comment: Your `ScrapeAsync` is async but you never await anything so your code runs synchonously.

Comment: The callback is always called in response to the event. You should check what's wrong in this case. Is there an exception? is the code actually *blocking* the main thread? If `ScrapeAsync` isn't async, it's actually running on the main thread, the same one that's trying to call `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Just because you used the `async` keyword doesn't mean the *method* will run in the background. It means you can use the `await` keyword to await an *already* asynchronous operation. If you wanted to avoid blocking you should have used asynchronous Selenium methods. If there aren't any, you could use `Task.Run` to run the method in the background

Comment: I wrapped the code in ScrapeAsync in await Task.Run() and it is working now.

Comment: @DavidStampher you should probably look for asynchronous Selenium methods too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos None of the selenium methods I am using in this example have async versions as far as I can see in Intellisense, but I will look into that thanks.